# Why does position: fixed; not work with justify-content: space-between;?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want to create a basic Navbar, which stays always on top of the page, even when you scroll. In Addition, the Navbar should be as wide as the width of the screen it is displayed on.

My current attempt is this:

CSS:

```
#header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:white;
}


#nav-list li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#header-img {
    width: 20vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav-list">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#function">Function</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

My attempt comes to this result:

[image: Result of my attempt. Does not take up the whole screen.]

However, as you can see, the navbar does not fill up the whole screen. The three links should be pushed to the side.

I am new to HTML/CSS and the only possible fix I currently know, would be:

```
width: 100%;
```

But I am pretty sure I should not do it like that. Thanks for you answers! :)

Comment: Have you added a width to your header? `width: 100vw;`

Comment: I think adding width:100% to the #header would work fine for fitting it to the entire width of the page, for staying in position even after scrolling, add top:0 to the same #header, I posted your code in JSFIDDLE and all these suggestions i made work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this will give it full width of the page and make it fit within the page.

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Adding width: 100vw; top: 0; left: 0; solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but to get a full width header I would use a grid and set your two columns `1fr auto` with a wide view width `95vw;` to avoid the right scroll bar;

Here I have the classic example of a your sticky header, a main that takes most of the space, then a sticky footer at the bottom. - so I could show your header indeed being stuck at the top but not scroll off.

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 95vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#nav-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header-img {
  width: 20vw;
}

.main{
  background-color: #DDDDFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img id="header-img" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="Logo">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#function">Function</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    I am body full
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer we have
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the position: fixed with justify-content: space-between
you will need to define the left:0 and the right:0

so you can write the css class like that:

```
 .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:white;
    }
```

also this attributes may help you

z-index: 150; to set the navbar in the above layer

width: 90%; to define the width of the items

margin: auto; to let the browser set the suitable spaces between the items